# .Net Core 3.1 dynamic object of type JsonElement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

We're migrating an Asp.Net Framework project to .Net Core 3.1. The sites uses SignalR and payload are sent from the frontend and received as dynamic object at the backend:

**Frontend**:

```js
var hostData = {
    "foo": "Bar"
};

connection.invoke("echo", hostData);
```

**Backend**:

```cs
public async Task echo(dynamic data)
{
    var fooValue = data.foo;  
}
```

This worked fine in .Net Framework but in .Net Core 3.1 it becomes a object (System.Text.JsonElement). I know I can use a strongly typed object instead, but as I don't want to update all methods, I'd rather keep it as a dynamic. - Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you read a simple value out of some json using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700678/how-do-you-read-a-simple-value-out-of-some-json-using-system-text-json)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski not really

Comment: @wmmhihaa did you find a solution for this? I'm running into this problem right now, I can see the object is type JsonElement but how does one work with it.