# Is there any way to get my json without creating a class

Tags: c#

From an API call I am getting some JSON data, I dont want to declare a class, while in NewtonSoft we can get those data as given below without creating a class,

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"example.json"));
Console.WriteLine(o1["customername"]);
```

Is there any similar way to get json data without creating a class in System.Text.Json

Edit:

I was able to proceed by the solutions provided here
[How do you read a simple value out of some json using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700678/how-do-you-read-a-simple-value-out-of-some-json-using-system-text-json)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using JSON document model and parse subsections you are interested in.
See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#deserialize-subsections-of-a-json-payload